# docker.build() in Jenkins pipeline with two tags

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

How can I set another tag for docker build step in the Jenkins pipeline which uses `docker.build()` script?

As for now I have:

```
docker.build("artifactory/docker/${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NO}")
```

and then

```
rtDockerPush(
  serverId: "Artifactory",
  image: "artifactory/docker/${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NO}",
  targetRepo: 'docker',
)
rtPublishBuildInfo(
  serverId: "Artifactory"
)
```

but I want to tag it with the `:latest` as well

I have tried something like:

```
docker.build("artifactory/docker/${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NO}","-t latest .")
```

but that is not working (it got published only with build number).

Any tips on that?

PS.
Based on the given answer I have ended up to have two calls for the push as follow:

```
rtDockerPush(
  serverId: "Artifactory",
  image: "artifactory/docker/${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NO}",
  targetRepo: 'docker',
)
rtDockerPush(
  serverId: "Artifactory",
  image: "artifactory/docker/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest",
  targetRepo: 'docker',
)
rtPublishBuildInfo(
  serverId: "Artifactory"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your build command to:

```
docker.build("test-alpine:123", "test-alpine:latest .")
```

It will produce the following bash command underhood:

```
docker build -t test-alpine:123 -t test-alpine:latest .
```

So probably need to put this code in your Jenkinsfile:

```
docker.build("artifactory/docker/${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NO}","-t artifactory/docker/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest .")
```

To push additional tag you can use `docker.push` command

```
def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")
customImage.push()

customImage.push('latest')
```

This is official docs code: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: It looks like it crates an image with the `:latest` but then it will publish only with the build number.

Comment: Ahh so you can use `docker.push("AdditionalTag");`

Comment: Yeah - I have ended up to have two `rtDockerPush` calls from the pipeline (updated OP with it). Thanks for the help!